Global Chrome Function not working in HTTP Toolkit
I just installed the HTTP Toolkit and try to use the "Global Chrome" function but i am not to use it so can you let me what should i do? If i use the independent chrome then it works it has only issue with the Global Chrome
I tried to read the documentation and other stuff like reset my pc but it didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
